# SDL and haskell problem in windows

Tags: windows, haskell, sdl

I asked before what libraries to use in haskell to program a game, and got quite nice answers that got me in the right direction. 
But i cant seem to solve a problem related to sdl binding. I've been following this tutorial [a haskell adventure in windows](http://www.animal-machine.com/blog/2010/04/a-haskell-adventure-in-windows/) (the installation part) to make a [simple sample works](http://www.animal-machine.com/blog/2010/04/getting-started-with-sdl-in-haskell/).
The problem comes when i try to run the example, i keep getting this error message from console when running ghci myExample.hs:

```
Loading package SDL-0.6.2 ... <interactive>: SDLmain: Cannot find specified module .
Can't load .so/.DLL for: SDLmain (addDLL: could not load DLL)
```

I have looked in many web pages and the solution or some help does not seem to appear.

Has this happend to annyone?

Comment: You have the .dll file in the same directory as the .exe, i presume?

Comment: i dont really undertsand. which .exe you mean? the ghc.exe?.
because there is no .exe of my code, its a .hs. 
im sorry, i really dont understand.

Comment: in the same directory as your compiled program

Comment: Speaking of which, *does* it work if you compile? In situations like this, getting things to work in GHCi can be slightly different from just compiling an executable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

`ghci MyExample.hs -l SDLmain`

Comment: Just to make sure, should it autoload that since when i do a 
  caball info sdl
it says that i have it installed already. Now that i mention this, im seeing that ive got 0.5.9 and 0.6.2 version installed, could this has something to do with the main question?

Comment: another question!! where is that sdlMain?

Comment: @llliax I dont' know anything about haskell on windows, thats what I'd use if I was on linux

Comment: @monadic -- This doesn't work on Windows, at least not for me. You also need the -L flag to give it the specific location of the library (because Windows doesn't have uniform library locations like /usr/lib, nor does it have anything like a package manager). But even with the -L flag, I have never been able to get SDL to work in GHCi on Windows. This is one of the reasons I switched to Linux for all my Haskell development. Dealing with external libraries in Windows is simply too much of a hassle.

Comment: @rtperson: I suspect this is why SDL includes the `sdl-config` utility. I'm using cygwin, so running `sdl-config --libs` gives me `-L/usr/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows`. I assume it should give sane results appropriate for however SDL was installed. That said, getting things to work in GHCi remains an exercise in frustration.